# flake8 only linting partial file in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8, linter

I've successfully setup flake8 in my python project (with a `.flake8` file in the root), and tied it to VS Code by way of a `.vscode/settings.json` file so that I see linter warnings in the file that I'm cleaning up. However, at line 1000, the linter support suddenly disappears. All lines following line 1000 do not provide linter feedback.

When I run `flake8 /path/to/file` from the command line, I get the full list of errors and their corresponding line numbers (including a number of warnings beyond line 1000), but for some reason VS Code seems to be unable to report these errors in-line in the IDE.

Is there some configuration I'm missing to allow VS Code to lint the rest of my large files beyond line 1000?

Comment: weird!  what vs code plugin are you using? I would suggest reporting this as a bug to them (they're probably doing something silly like `/:[0-9]{1,3}/` to grab the line number)

Comment: @wdc92 -You could submit this question here: [microsoft/vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Thanks @JillCheng and Anthony - I will consider posting a bug on  [ms-python's](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) GitHub page. It seems to fix itself after some time. I left the file open in VS Code over night, and it works again. However, restarting VS Code presents the problem again. I suppose the linter is just running very slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, I found the issue. I was using `black` and `flake8` in the `settings.json` file for vscode, and apparently, `black` was hitting a syntax error that I had introduced higher up in the file (around line 1000). This caused a silent failure of the linter sequence that VS code is running to present the "error squiggly lines".

When running a pre-commit hook (`pre-commit run -a`) that runs all 3 linters (`black`, `iSort`, and `flake8`), the syntax error was reported by `black` and easily fixed, but when run "on save" in VS-code, it fails silently and stops reporting inline errors in the IDE.

With the syntax error fixed, running `flake8` from the command line returns the expected number of warnings/errors, and VS Code again shows the squiggly lines on errors, for the full file, regardless of length.